# Yii 2 giving an exception when clicking on the default contact tab

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am getting this error when I run on my mac with localhost.

> Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP
>   extension with PNG support is required.

[image]

I think the problem comes with the PNG picture that is being rendered by default on the contact page. All of the code is the basic code that is given by the Yii framework: [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.5/yii-basic-app-2.0.5.tgz) Only happens when I click the `Contact` tab on the navigation bar.

[image]

Comment: Remove captcha from form or install php-gd or php-imagick extension http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

Comment: This `PNG picture` is a captcha image

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For solve problem, first install `php-gd` module on your system. After that open `php.ini` on your editor and search for `;extension=gd.so` and remove the heading **;** sign. Then restart your apache service ;).

For Arch Linux you can do followings (Lines that begins with `#` are command of terminal):

- `# pacman -S php-gd`
- `# vim /etc/php/php.ini`
- Press `/` and type `gd` then press `Enter`
- Find `;extension=gd.so` and convert it into `extension=gd.so` by moving cursor on `;` sign and press `x`
- Press `Esc` and type `:wq` and press `Enter`
- `# systemctl restart httpd.service`

Answer (score 4):

With this two lines it is okeyokay:

```
sudo apt install php-gd

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments.

The contact form contains a .png picture in the form of a captcha image. The captcha image is used there to prevent spam being send via the contact form.

- You can edit the view page and remove the captcha
- You can install php-gd or [php-imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) extension

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the latest version I tried downloading ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll from [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/). That one actually worked with the php_imagick.dll (Imagick for PHP 5.5.x) from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/.

This is not the latest version but it worked. (even without restarting the computer)

Answer (score 0):

Infact in Windows 10 environment, installed with WAMP Server, it was a matter of copying php.ini file to C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin\

It was missing at that location.

Answer (score 0):

Try un-commenting `extension=gd2` in php.ini. Then restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, if you already install php > 7.0, then Check php_gd2.dll is in your extension directory and uncomment ;extension=gd2 of your php.ini.

Comment: windows, default php.ini file is comment this gd extension, so we only need to uncomment and restart php-fpm process.

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the extension=gd and restart dev server with command  php yii serve

restarting apache server from xampp control won't help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).