# Error: Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support is required

Tags: php, macos, yii, gd, freetype

I'm on MacOS Mojave with Apache. I'm getting following error on a fresh yii 2 install on contact page

Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Either GD PHP extension with FreeType support or ImageMagick PHP extension with PNG support is required

I've gd enabled with PNG support. I've php7

What else I need to do to fix this error?

[image: GD config]

Comment: What about reading the error message: have you made sure that you've installed the FreeType parts? You would see it in `phpinfo` if they were installed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813738/yii-2-giving-an-exception-when-clicking-on-the-default-contact-tab

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to install ImageMagick. See [ImageMagick Brew installation with PHP Module in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865600/imagemagick-brew-installation-with-php-module-in-mac-os-x) for details.

Comment: It's twisted mess. No one has any clue what they have to do get it working. I've installed brew install imagemagick after that can#'t figure out what to do. I'm on php 7 so not sure what to do next. That question doesn't help.